# Dynamic type column in dynamicjasper

Tags: java, forms, dynamic-jasper

I'm using dynamic jasper to print a form in vertical format(one column for labels and one for values). by now I was using a string column and convert form values to string. 
But now I should handle image fields. how can I have an image in some rows and some text in others in the same column?

Comment: can you share the code written so far ?

Comment: The code isn't so smile that I can put it here. The related part, simply add 2 string columns.